# PHP Object created in __construct Not Accesible inside function of same Class

Tags: php, oop, object, model-view-controller

PHP website developed using **MVC** pattern. i want access an object created using constructor in all functions of class. when i check `is_object` its not there so i create object one more time.

When try to simulate the MVC pattern its working fine(*below code*) getting `Object Accessible: $this->ldap Logged In!`. But in my actual website getting as `Non-Object: $this->ldap Logged In!`

> What could be possible mistakes i done? is there anyway to find what
>   is the issue?

```
class ldap{
    function ldap_userAuth(){
        return TRUE;
    }
}

class commonfunctions {
    private $ldap;
    public function __construct(){
        $this->ldap=new ldap();
    }
    function userLogin(){
        if(!is_object($this->ldap)){
            $this->ldap=new ldap();
            echo 'Non-Object: $this->ldap'.PHP_EOL;
        }
        else{ 
            echo 'Object Accessible: $this->ldap'.PHP_EOL; 
        }
        if($this->ldap->ldap_userAuth()){
            return TRUE;
        }
        else{ 
            return FALSE; 
        }
    }
}

class Model extends commonfunctions {
}

class Controller {
    public $model;

    public function __construct(){  
        $this->model = new Model(); 
    }

    public function invoke(){
        if($this->model->userLogin()){
            echo 'Logged In!'.PHP_EOL;
        }
        else{ 
            echo 'Logged Out!'.PHP_EOL; 
        }
    }
}

$controller = new Controller();
$controller->invoke();
```

*Note:- classes are included in the above order for my actual website.
Above Code snippet is working as expected i have issue only in live website.*

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the `__construct` method of the parent in the `Model` class like this:

```
class Model extends commonfunctions {
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

to make sure that the constructor is being called.

Comment: constructor is called without using `parent::__construct();` and object is created. Issue for me is when trying to use `$this->ldap` it is destroyed at some point. So i'll check `is_object` and creating object one more time. i cannot do this for all functions in a class. Still looking for solution

Comment: There's no way the object is being destroyed based on the code above!
could you please provide any extra info about your code?